# MySQL query combination of CONCAT, GROUP_CONCAT, and DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I have this three tables with their relations.

```
people
    people_id          (int)
    people_name        (varchar)

comic
    comic_id           (int)
    comic_name         (varchar)

ref_author
    comic_id           (int)
    people_writer_id   (int)
    people_illust_id   (int)
```

Relationships on ref_author are as following.

- comic_id refers to comic's comic_id
- Both people_writer_id and
  people_illust_id refers to people's people_id, as any particular
  people on people_id could be a writer, illustrator, or both.
- When there are, example, of two writers and one illustrator, I'd insert
  the table with the first writer and illustrator, then the second writer and the first illustrator (filling the gap with duplicate)

Using this query,

```
SELECT distinct SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    c.comic_name, concat (group_CONCAT(distinct pa.people_name separator ' / '), ', ', group_CONCAT(distinct pb.people_name separator ' / ')) as 'author' 
FROM ref_author ra 
inner join comic c on c.comic_id = ra.comic_id 
inner join people pa on pa.people_id = ra.people_writer_id 
inner join people pb on pb.people_id = ra.people_illust_id 
group by c.comic_name
```

I could display this kind of result.

```
comic_name         author
17+                Kharisma Jati, Kharisma Jati
1SR6               Muhammad Fathanatul Haq, Muhammad Fathanatul Haq
304th Study Room   Felicia Huang, Felicia Huang
4HERO              Arief Prasojo, Arief Prasojo
5 cm               Donny Dhirgantoro, Is Yuniarto
....
Degalings          Pandji Pragiwaksono, Pandji Pragiwaksono / Shani ...
```

The problem with this query, the author column will display nicely when one people only referred to one position but when one people referred to two positions, it will display as duplicates. My aim is to display the data without duplicates such as this.

```
comic_name         author
17+                Kharisma Jati 
1SR6               Muhammad Fathanatul Haq 
304th Study Room   Felicia Huang 
4HERO              Arief Prasojo 
5 cm               Donny Dhirgantoro, Is Yuniarto
....
Degalings          Pandji Pragiwaksono, Shani ...
```

How do I do that? Where do I modify the query, or is there any flaw in the table?

Comment: UPDATE: I've managed to accomplish this feat using query from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485901/mysql-concat-ws-without-duplicates but it only displays two names at maximum.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your data, you're taking the author value from 2 different places, `ra.people_writer_id` and `ra.people_illust_id`.
Since in your output these names are separated by a comma, these means the names appear in both fields, so Kharisma Jati for example is both a writer and an illustrator.

If this is the case, and you do not want a name to show up twice when they act as both writer and illustrator, you would need to change this bit of your query:

```
concat (group_CONCAT(distinct pa.people_name separator ' / '), ', ', group_CONCAT(distinct pb.people_name separator ' / ')) as 'author'
```

and use distinct between both of the fields, and your output would not look as it does now.. So for example, you could do

```
group_CONCAT(distinct pa.people_name,pb.people_name separator ' , ') as 'author'
```

This will avoid name repetitions. However, this will only list the unique names between the combination of these two values separated by comma, and you would not see the separation between writers and illustrators.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for unfortunately. The output looks exactly as what I've inputted to the ref_author table. So for a comic with one writer and two illustrators for example, the output looks like "Pandji PragiwaksonoPandji Pragiwaksono, Pandji PragiwaksonoShani Budi Pandita".